# How to prevent stack overflow error in javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, stack-overflow

I have a javascript function called MakeInput.

It has got approximately 150 lines.

And I have to call that function about 300 times in my code.

My C# code called that function through webbrowser control.

It has to call that function 300 times, until DataTable in C# finishes looping.

But maybe javascript in webbrowser thinks that I am calling an infinite recursive function, so when it comes to about 60 times, it always throws an error called stack overflow at line 38.

How can I prevent this error?

How can I do a long time function in javascript?

**EDIT**

OK.

I am posting my code.

Here it goes.

**C#**

```
ieBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("setPageIndex", new object[] { currentPage });
ieBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("fnSearch");
```

**JavaScript**

```
function fnSearch() {
    var frm = document.searchFrm;
    var str = encryptData(frm, _currentPage);
}

function encryptData(form, _currentPage) {
    var retValue    = "";
    try {
        var crypto          = document.getElementById("SomeActiveX");
        var resultVal       = MakeInput(form);
        var inputStr        = "";

        if (resultVal[0] != "" && resultVal[1] != "") {
            inputStr    = resultVal[0] + "&" + resultVal[1];
        }
        else if (resultVal[0] == "") {
            inputStr    = resultVal[1];
        }
        else if (resultVal[1] == "") {
            inputStr    = resultVal[0];
        }
        else {
            inputStr    = "";
        }
        retValue        = crypto.Encrypt(inputStr);
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
    return retValue;
}

function MakeInput(form) {
    var result = new Array(2);
    try {
        var keyProc = document.getElementById("SomeActiveX");
        var name = new Array(form.elements.length);
        var value = new Array(form.elements.length);
        var enc_name = new Array();
        var enc_value = new Array();
        var enc_idx = 0;
        var j = 0;
        var len = form.elements.length;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if ((form.elements[i].type != "button") && (form.elements[i].type != "reset") &&
                (form.elements[i].type != "submit")) {
                if ((form.elements[i].type == "radio") || (form.elements[i].type == "checkbox")) {
                    if (form.elements[i].checked == true) {
                        name[j] = form.elements[i].name;
                        value[j] = form.elements[i].value;
                        j++;
                    }
                }
                else if ((form.elements[i].type == "text") || (form.elements[i].type == "password")) {
                    name[j] = form.elements[i].name;
                    value[j] = form.elements[i].value;
                    j++;

                    if (keyProc != null && (form.elements[i].getAttribute("enc") == "on")) {
                        enc_name[enc_idx] = "_E2E_" + form.elements[i].name;
                        enc_value[enc_idx] = keyProc.GetEncData("", form.name, form.elements[i].name);
                        enc_idx++;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (form.elements[i].type == "select-one") {
                        var ind = form.elements[i].selectedIndex;
                        var singleLen = form.elements[i].length;
                        if (singleLen > 0) {
                            if (ind >= 0) {
                                name[j] = form.elements[i].name;
                                value[j] = form.elements[i].options[ind].value;
                                j++;
                            }
                            else {
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                        }
                    }
                    else if (form.elements[i].type == "select-multiple") {
                        var multiLen = form.elements[i].length;
                        for (k = 0; k < multiLen; k++) {
                            if (form.elements[i].options[k].selected) {
                                name[j] = form.elements[i].name;
                                value[j] = form.elements[i].options[k].value;
                                j++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        name[j] = form.elements[i].name;
                        value[j] = form.elements[i].value;
                        j++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var flag1 = false;
        var flag2 = false;
        var signed_text = "";
        var unsigned_text = "";
        for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            if (name[i].charAt(0) != "_") {
                if (flag1) {
                    signed_text += "&";
                }
                else {
                    flag1 = true;
                }
                signed_text += name[i];
                signed_text += "=";
                signed_text += escape_url(value[i]);
            }
            else {
                if (flag2) {
                    unsigned_text += "&";
                }
                else {
                    flag2 = true;
                }
                unsigned_text += name[i];
                unsigned_text += "=";
                unsigned_text += escape_url(value[i]);
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < enc_idx; i++) {
            if (flag2) {
                unsigned_text += "&";
            }
            else {
                flag2 = true;
            }
            unsigned_text += enc_name[i];
            unsigned_text += "=";
            unsigned_text += enc_value[i];
        }
        if (enc_idx > 0) {
            if (flag2) {
                unsigned_text += "&";
            }
            else {
                flag2 = true;
            }

            unsigned_text += "_ENCSEED";
            unsigned_text += "=";
            unsigned_text += keyProc.GetEncData(serverCert, "", "");
        }
        result[0] = signed_text;
        result[1] = unsigned_text;
    }
    catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return result;
}
```

And the error message was captured.

[image]

Sorry, the error message is written in Korean.

But it says, "Stack overflow(at line 38)".

But I think the number is not pointing at the line number, coz I've changed lines but the error message is always 38.

Comment: Maybe by posting the code?

Comment: @user2738336 What do you mean by that? Can you give me some more specific clues?

Comment: Post your code... I don't know what line 38 looks like. Nobody can help you here until you post some code. It's hard to understand what you are trying to do just with your words.

Comment: It is likely that a semi-infinite recursion in the javascript is causing the stack overflow, but no answer can be provided without showing us your code.

Comment: Post Code! also post the Stack Overflow message

Comment: Don't post the code... 150 lines per function is way too long. Make it shorter/refactor first and post *only* one small function that causes issues.

Comment: @user2738336 I've posted my code.

Comment: @abc123 I've posted my code.

Comment: @JoshuaSon you need to functionalize your code.  Simply take your code and break it into functions when you notice the code is the same, make 1 function for the code that is the same.  This will reduce your code tremendously.

Comment: @JoshuaSon here is my code reduction for you. http://jsfiddle.net/9kWAF/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't think you are in a continuous loop.  It fails when memory runs out in stack. The same code might work on a computer with higher memory.  Each time a function is called a stack entry is kept in stack to move to calee once the function is done, so in your case the stack space runs out after 60 calls. The line 38 is not line number in your code.

Why dont you try same code on a high end PC